# replace text between rangy position

Tags: jquery, rangy

I have a keyup event

```
editor.on('keyup', function(e) {
    selection = rangy.getSelection()
    start = selection.anchorOffset;
    end = selection.focusOffset;
    // start and end will give the position consider (2, 4)
    // Where 2 is start position
    // and 4 is end position
});
```

I would like to replace the text between the position 2 and 4. How can I make this possible through Rangy.

**editor** is contenteeditble container.

Consider the following example

***This is a testing text***

Now the caret position is after `Th`
so I want to replace `at` instead of `is`. I have positions in hand (3,4)

Comment: replace with? do you mean replace with each other or some other value??

Comment: @atmd please check whether you can understand my edited question with example